# discord.py 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'reactions' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def voto(ctx, id, num_people):
    msg = ctx.fetch_message(id)
    winners = []
    total_users = []
    reactions = msg.reactions
    for reaction in reactions:
        users = await reaction.users().flatten()
        for user in users:
            total_users.append(user)
    for i in range(num_people):
        winners.append(i.name)
    winners_msg = '\n'.join(winners)
    await ctx.send(f"{winners_msg}\nHas won")
```

I get the below error in the above code

```
  File ".\Testing.py", line 24, in voto
    reactions = msg.reactions
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'reactions'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I want to fix But I get an error
Please help me

I used a translator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `ctx.fetch_message(id)` is a coroutine, so it should be awaited, that is the error you are getting.

Replace that line with:

`msg = await ctx.fetch_message(id)`

Comment: `for i in range(num_people):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`
I'm getting that error

Comment: Use `for in in range(int(num_people))`. Although a best practice would be having a more defined function:  `async def voto(ctx, id: int, num_people: int):`